# How to move icon to the right?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to move the icon to the right?

```
 <Grid container justify="space-between" border="1px">  
    <Typography variant="h6" className="locationTitle" display="block">
        sample text
    </Typography>
    <LocationIcon align="right"/>
</Grid>
```

current

[image]

desired

[image]

Comment: There is many way.. you can set "gap" in your Grid container, margin... what you should It's depends on your Design goal.

Comment: where should i put margin? in the icon?

Comment: If you put margin in Icon, it should be margin-left. If you margin in Typograph, it will be margin-right.

Comment: I've tried already that but it has no effect

Comment: `margin-left="100px"` on the icon but it has no effect

Comment: check the width of grid, set it to full

Comment: I've put on the `<Grid>` `width="100%"` and on the icon `margin-left:100px` it has no effect

Comment: @kaito the code you posted is working see this https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-shape-6e88m?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do this

```
    <Grid container>
      <Grid container direction="column" item xs align="left">  
          <Grid item >
            <Typography>
              sample text
            </Typography>
          </Grid>        
      </Grid>
      <Grid container direction="column" item xs align="right">  
          <Grid item >
          < LocationIcon/>
          </Grid>        
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: it works !! thanks